# How to truncate decimal in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, truncate

The function TRUNCATE works in MySQL but I get an error in Microsoft SQL Server : Incorrect syntax near (
Basically I have list of value under discount. (Some with lots of decimal)
I just want to keep the 2 decimal without rounding.
E.g from 110.975 to 110.97, 10.259 to 10.25. How do I go about doing that?

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(110.975,2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use round this way

```
ROUND (110.975 , 2 , 1 )

ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
```

> function Is the type of operation to perform. function must be
>   tinyint, smallint, or int. When function is omitted or has a value of
>   0 (default), numeric_expression is rounded. When a value other than 0
>   is specified, numeric_expression is truncated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms175003(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN